# Having a problem validating the date in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
guid = str(uuid.uuid4())
username = config.username
dbpassword = config.dbpassword
dbhost = config.dburl
engine =  create_engine('mysql://%s:%s@%s/db?charset=utf8' %(username, dbpassword, dbhost), encoding="utf-8")
path = 'd:/anaconda3/lib/bin/'
jsonFiles = os.listdir(path)
maxSnapshotQuery = '''SELECT MAX(Snapshot) AS Snapshot FROM %s''' 

for file in jsonFiles:
    tableName = file.split(".")[0]
    snapshotCheck = pd.read_sql_query(maxSnapshotQuery %tableName, engine)
    print(snapshotCheck['Snapshot'].dt.date)
    if snapshotCheck['Snapshot'].dt.date == datetime.datetime.now().date():
        with open(path+file) as f :
         try:
             rawJson = json.load(f)
             rawJson['authorizations'][0]['id'] = guid
             print(f.name + ' Load Completed')
         except ValueError as error:
             print(error + ' ' + f.name + ' Check the JSON within')
             continue


        createSession()
        createJob(session)
        loadData(data, engine)
```

I am trying to makes sure that the snapshot for the day has not been taken yet and put into the database.  If it has skip that load and move on to the next (that happens in another part of the code), but I can't seem to get the if statement to take  the date from the dataframe and match it to the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
for file in jsonFiles:
    tableName = file.split(".")[0]
    snapshotDate = pd.read_sql_query(maxSnapshotQuery %tableName, engine, parse_dates=['Snapshot'])

if snapshotDate.Snapshot[0].date() != datetime.datetime.now().date() :
    with open(path+file) as f :
     try:
         rawJson = json.load(f)
         rawJson['authorizations'][0]['id'] = guid
         print(f.name + ' Load Completed')
     except:
         print(f.name + ' Check the JSON within')
         continue


    createSession()
    createJob(session)
    loadData(data, engine)
else:
    print('Data already loaded for today for ' + file)
```

parsed the object like a K,V pair and then applied date to it.